# Formatting the EXCEL(.xlsx) document? jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, excel

Help who faced, how to make the formatting of the XLSX document ?

When exporting a table, `<table>` does not accept the values `<br/>` (New line)

*Result:*

[image]

But if you click on the cells, it looks like this:

*Result click:*

[image]

**How to make the transfer to a new line automatically?**

[Library TableExport jquery](https://tableexport.v5.travismclarke.com/#tableexport)

*P.S Sorry for my english I'm using GOOGLE TRANSLATE :)*

Comment: @pnuts garbage so. They do not know
  [LINK](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/838098/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-excel-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-jquery?noredirect=1#comment1342832_838098)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find how to do this with similar libraries.

Implemented through PHP, it was easier.

I created the export_xls.php file in it using jQuery and HTML passed the table and downloaded it.

```
<?php 
 $table = $_POST['HTMLTABLE'];

 $xls_file="Export table.xls"; 

 header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8'");
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$xls_file");

 echo $table; 
?>
```

---

Result:

[image]